# Query all Content Notes of an opportunity

Tags: soql, query, contentnote

How would I query the `ContentNotes` of an opportunity? I'm able to query all the `ContentDocumentLink` and able to get the `ContentDocument` but the `ContentDocument` does not have the fields that I'm looking for, mainly body or content.

Comment: because `ContentVersion` (which is where the actual body data resides) can support GB files, you can run into heap issues so you may need to revisit your design to ensure you won't hit these limits

Answer (score 3):

The link between ContentNote and any related record is stored in the ContentDocumentLink. So, if you're writing a trigger or Executing Anonymous Code, you need to query all ContentDocumentLinks related to your Opportunity. So, something like this:

```
Map<Id,List<ContentNote>> noteMap = new Map<Id,List<ContentNote>>();

    for(ContentDocumentLink links : [SELECT LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId FROM ContendDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityID = '006xxOppId']){
        List<ContentNote> notes = noteMap.get(links.LinkedEntityId);
        if(notes == null){
            notes = new List<ContentNote>();
            notes.add(links.ContentDocumentId);
            noteMap.put(links.LinkedEntityID, notes);
        }
        else{
            notes.add(links.ContentDocumentId);
        }

}
```

This gives you a map of all ContentNotes for whatever Opportunity it is that you're indicating. Then you could loop over the list to do whatever it is that you're wanting to do.

```
    for(ContentNote cn : noteMap.get('Enter your oppId here'){
      //do something with your note records
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to query `ContentNote` [object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm). Here is the schema for [ContentNote Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm):

[image: ContentNote Objects]